# Outlook VBA - go to specific public folder wthout giving the complete folder name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, public-folders

I usually need to go to some specific folders to see the containing emails.
These folders are in Outlook exchange public folders.
I have managed to write a script that I can enter the full name of the folder that I need to go to in a pop window and it takes me there.
an example of the name of the subfolder is

**ELD/13/1746/22 - (ANT) - FUEL ANALYSIS FROM BUNKERING AT GONGAVARAM, INDIA**

I would like to know if there is a way to be able to give only the first part of the folder name folder (e.g. in this case would be ELD/13/1746/22) and the script would be able to go without the need to enter the complete folder name.
NOTE: this first part is a reference number and is unique, so there is no way there would be 2 the same.

I hereby am also giving the script I wrote and wondering if is possible to use some kind of wildcard to complete the name of the folder.

```
Sub PickFolder()
'Update by Extendoffice 20180504
Dim xNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim xPickFolder As folder
Dim xExplorer As Explorer
On Error Resume Next
Set xNameSpace = Outlook.Application.Session
Set xPickFolder = xNameSpace.PickFolder
If TypeName(xPickFolder) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
Set xExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
xExplorer.Close
xPickFolder.Display
Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMaximized
Set xPickFolder = Nothing
Set xNameSpace = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.folder
    Dim TestFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
 
    On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set TestFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not TestFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = TestFolder.Folders
            Set TestFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If TestFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolder = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
     
   'Return the TestFolder
    Set GetFolder = TestFolder
    Exit Function
 
GetFolder_Error:
    Set GetFolder = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
 
Sub TestGetFolder()
    Dim folder As Outlook.folder
    Dim Refno
    Refno = InputBox(promt, "REF. No.")
    If Left(Refno, 3) = "RUB" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.2 M/V RUBY -ex LADY AMNA\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "ELD" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.3 Vessel name A\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "OMN" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.4 Vessel name B\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "ELI" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.5 Vessel name C\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "SIB" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.6 Vessel name D\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "ZIM" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.7 Vessel name E\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "EME" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.8 Vessel name F\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "SID" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.9 Vessel name G\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "SAN" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.9 Vessel name H\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    ElseIf Left(Refno, 3) = "MBL" Then
    Set folder = GetFolder("\\Public folders - xxx.xxx@xxx.com\all public folders\~technical-Purchasing\2.91 Vessel name I\2.reqs\2022\" & Refno)
    End If
    If Not (folder Is Nothing) Then
        folder.Display
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `For Each ... Next` construct ([For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement)) where you test the folder name using the `Like` function:

```
For Each tmp In Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
If tmp.Name Like TestValue & "*" Then
...
End If
Next tmp
```

Also you might like the `Select Case` structure ([Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement)) so that you need get the left 3 characters of Refno only once.